# Tab space in ASP.NET listbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms, listbox

Anyone know how to insert tab characters in an ASP.NET listbox?
I want to use it so that all my items are lined up because i have two fields on each line a number and a name.
In winforms all I have to do is:

```
Listbox.Items.Add(number + "\t" + name);
```

But in ASP.NET Webforms this doesnt work any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the ASP.NET listbox, you can't do this. Why don't you use a GridView control instead ?

Comment: I need to be the user to be able to select an item and then do processing from that selection, I didnt think you could do that with a gridview

Comment: Its not a problem to make a GridView selectable: http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webforms/controls/allowinguserstoselectrowsingridview.aspx

or: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/view9FC28EE6-ACB0-4F51-BFE4-38B0B10134D5.htm